# C# 5 Async Await .Task.Factory.StartNew cancellation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the async code that implements cancellation token. It's working but Im not pretty sure if this is the right way to do it so I just want feedback about it.

Here is the actual code:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private async void SaveData() {

    if (GetActiveServiceRequest() != null)
    {
        var tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();


        this.ShowWizardPleaseWait("Saving data...");

        var someTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            bool returnVal = false;

            // Set sleep of 7 seconds to test the 5 seconds timeout.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);

            if (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // if not cancelled then save data

                App.Data.EmployeeWCF ws = new App.Data.EmployeeWCF ();
                returnVal = ws.UpdateData(_employee.Data);
                ws.Dispose();
            }

            return returnVal;

        }, tokenSource.Token);


        if (await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny(someTask, System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000)) == someTask)
        {
            // Completed
            this.HideWizardPleaseWait();
            if (someTask.Result)
            {
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort;
            }
            btnOK.Enabled = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();

            // Timeout logic
            this.HideWizardPleaseWait();
            MessageBox.Show("Timeout. Please try again.")
        }


    }
}
```

Does async / await / cancellation code is well implemented?

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use [`CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229.aspx) constructor to set the cancellation after 5 seconds.

Also, `Task.Run` method is a recommended way to run compute-bound tasks (see remark [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321421.aspx)).

Other issues worth noting:

- by conventions asynchronous methods should have a suffix `Async`
- `using` keyword is a recommended way to correctly dispose `IDisposable` objects
- if a task to be cancelled cannot return correct results (according to business requirements) it's recommended to throw `OperationCanceledException` by calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method.

  ```
  private async void SaveDataAsync() 
  {
      if (GetActiveServiceRequest() == null)
          return;

      var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Token;
      this.ShowWizardPleaseWait("Saving data...");

      var someTask = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
      {
          // Set sleep of 7 seconds to test the 5 seconds timeout.
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);

          cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

          // if not cancelled then save data
          using (App.Data.EmployeeWCF ws = new App.Data.EmployeeWCF())
          {
              return ws.UpdateData(_employee.Data);
          }
      }, cancellationToken);

      try
      {
          this.DialogResult = await someTask
              ? DialogResult.OK
              : DialogResult.Abort;

          btnOK.Enabled = true;
          this.Close();
      }
      catch(OperationCanceledException)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Timeout. Please try again.")
      }
      finally
      {
          this.HideWizardPleaseWait();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I had been pulling my hair out using the `Task.Delay()` method in the question where tasks would `RunToCompletion` regardless of a call to `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`. Refactored my `Task` manager to use this method and it all just works. Thanks.